# Is U3D the only supported file format for PDF

Tags: pdf, uwp, itext, .net-standard

Can one only add U3D file formats to a PDF or is there other formats? And is there maybe a nuget package or library that I can use to convert my glb or fbx formats to u3d in .net standard (UWP)?

Comment: "And is there maybe a nuget package or library" software recommendations should be asked here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ not here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Can one only add U3D file formats to a PDF or is there other formats?

The PDF 2.0 ISO specification has added the PRC format to PDF standard.
https://3dpdfconsortium.org/prc/